# Transform return type of all function in the class while preserve generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm finding a way to transform the return type of all functions in the class.
While it needs to preserve generic.

Given a MyService class

```
class CustomPromise<T> extends Promise<T> {
  customData: string;
}

interface RespSomething {
  data: string;
}

interface RespWhatever {
  data: number;
}

class MyService {
  something(req: { x: string; y: string }): CustomPromise<RespSomething> {
    return new CustomPromise<RespSomething>((res, req) => {});
  }

  whatever(req: { a: string }): CustomPromise<RespWhatever> {
    return new CustomPromise<RespWhatever>((res, req) => {});
  }
}
```

I want to transform the type into

```
interface TransformedMyService {
  something(req: { x: string; y: string }): Promise<RespSomething>;
  whatever(req: { a: string }): Promise<RespWhatever>;
}
```

I scratched my head around.
Is this even possible in typescript?

Comment: @jcalz I've cleared out errors in the code.

Comment: @jcalz Oh man, This worked like a charm.
Please add the answer below I'll make it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done via a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where you use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to extract the method argument types and the type argument for `CustomPromise<T>`:

```
type TransformedMyService = { [K in keyof MyService]:
  MyService[K] extends { (...args: infer A): CustomPromise<infer R> } ?
  { (...args: A): Promise<R> } :
  MyService[K]
}
```

Which results in:

```
/*
type TransformedMyService = {
    something: (req: {
        x: string;
        y: string;
    }) => Promise<RespSomething>;
    whatever: (req: {
        a: string;
    }) => Promise<RespWhatever>;
}
*/
```

as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCCuEAuB7AtgBQE7oJYQFMAeAFQD5oCAPJAgOwBMZs9DSKBvAKGmmEVRoAImCRgAXNGRZcdAObQAvNABEs3ElxgQuAF4EVAbi4BfLl1m0sAMzDAC0AEoEIABwDK6AkgAWshdy8DKISUkgy8sZmFnRWtvZOLq4A6j6iBABuBFjQgdDBYpJ08GgARtlR5qCQMACyAJ7u2Rm4CXkQXr7+ABRYBACOkhzQVJLS-obQ9WPh-tAmAJSSCMjoLGj4xM5unmjefvKcPLzQfUjwWHTQdAQA7nACazgbbNsenQdyZN29LgA0pwGCyUnHmC2MvGivFuaVoWSwv0GuWgoXG8jBy0emGemyIb1S6XhRxOgPOl2udweq2xrC2SQJcOy31+EABfX6wMUoMWEPmpnMSHqrgcJCwYDoEGsKCwewYDSaWBaCWUwwA2gBpaCyaAAawI9RQ1mg8uarQIAF1xMcTYqzRrzZQaPQmMjugA6D1gLByCCSWTWbLQACCSypgnWuP9gccFBM0AA-Mdhu7Pd7fcHQxHXrHoFbeDalQR7fyuAB6ABUXEFwugovFkulsoLZqUuWOvA6ey68kkiKG7ZJIxmETkvMHU2HEwHixB0CzdJ2H38ZDH0BhhOyvfZ-fHvFRs0i085FHnePpsMyTMq5dLQA)

Comment: I've just found out that my CustomPromise can actually be any type.
Is there a way to handle any generic type (any<T>)?

Comment: Nope, sorry.  Not without higher kindred types as requested in microsoft/TypeScript#1213, and even with them it might be impossible because the type system is structural and not nominal.  I would go on but this is out of scope here.

Comment: I luckily found that since all CustomPromise(s) are inherited from Promise. I could use `Promise<infer R>` instead of `CustomPromise<infer R>`.
This totally solved me. Thanks a ton for your help!